# Delete Duplicate rows on Google sheet by comparing only certain values on certain columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Sheet 1

```
Timestamp           |Name | Shift.....| Date....| Letter..|    
19/05/2016 15:44:46|Mark | Swap      |  02/AUG | S       |    
Timestamp2           |Ivon | Give away | 25/ AUG | G       |    
Timestamp3           |Laura| Take      | 01/AUG  | A       |     
Timestamp4           |Ann  | Take      | 02/AUG  | A       |    
Timestamp5           |Ann  | Give away | 03/AUG  | G       |
Timestamp6           |Laura| Delete    | 01/AUG  | D       |
```

As this is a google sheet, I am trying to run the below script to delete rows which matches Name and Date Columns. E.G. Laura has 2 entries on the same date of 01AUG. Therefore I want both rows to be deleted. I am trying the following script but it doesn't work.

```
    function removeDuplicates() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 2");
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if( row[0] == newData[j][1] && row[1] == newData[j][3]){
  duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
 }
```

Comment: You need `row[0] == newData[j][0] && row[1] == newData[j][1]`, in order to compare values in the same columns. Here, [0] refers to timestamp column and [1] to the name column.

Comment: Hi Sandwich! Thanks for the reply. I need to compare Name Column and Date Column and delete the matching rows. I have tried both the row[0] == newData[j][0] && row[1] == newData[j][1] entry and this one  row[1] == newData[j][0] && row[3] == newData[j][1] but nothings working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v4. Final (I think).

*If Cx is "delete" or "Delete" delete row x and rows whose B and D are same as row x's.*

```
function objTst(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 2");

  var megarng = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //[][]

  var rodel = [0]; //rows to delete

  for (i = 0; i<megarng.length; i++){
    if (String(megarng[i][1])==("Delete"||"delete")){ //megarng[][x] 0=b, 1=c, 2=d
      rodel.push(i+2) 

      for (g=0; g<megarng.length ; g++){

        if(String(megarng[g][0])===String(megarng[i][0]) && String(megarng[g][2])===String(megarng[i][2])){

          rodel.push(g+2);

          Logger.log(megarng[g][0]);
          Logger.log(megarng[i][0]);
          Logger.log(megarng[g][2]);
          Logger.log(megarng[i][2]);

          Logger.log(i+"i");
          Logger.log(g);
        }
      }
    }
    rodel.sort(function comp(a,b){return a-b});
    Logger.log(rodel);
  }
  for (i=rodel.length-1 ; 0<i; i--){if (rodel[i-1]!==rodel[i]){sheet.deleteRow(rodel[i]);}}
}
```

Comment: Hi Jose! Thanks for the help.. but its not working :(  maybe I should try to find a way to 1.) over write the previous entry when NAME and DATE are similar 2.) when a entry of a "Delete" appears in the "SHIFT" column, then search for the NAME and DATE of the previous entry and delete the both new and old entry.. 3.) in case there are no previous entry found, just delete the new Delete entry raw.  Appreciate any help.. thanks a ton

Comment: I noticed the error. I edited my answer such that if the values of cells Bx and By are equal and the values of cells Dx and Dy are equal, then rows x and y will be deleted.
On your comment
1) did you mean that only row y would be deleted?
2) I think this is what I fixed just now but does not take the presence of "Delete" into account.
3) what did you mean by "Delete entry raw"?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jose! YOU AMAZINGLY AWESOME.. ITS WORKING.. :)

Comment: Hi Jose! I think I haven't properly explained the issue. Basically I want this script to run only for Delete a shift request. With your script, it deletes every duplicate entry.  E.g. if Ann by mistake enter the same entry twice |Ann |Take| 02/AUG , it will get deleted. I don't want that to happen. When someone wants to remove their previous entry like |Laura| Take| 01/AUG| and then she send the request  |Laura| Delete|01/AUG| then only those entries to be deleted. Incase someone send a Delete request by mistake for none existing, it should get deleted. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Edited my answer. If the row has "delete", get its columns b and d, find and delete rows with the same values for columns b and d, then delete the row.

Comment: Hi Jose! thanks for your time and efforts.. I think its not working properly. it is deleting some rows which are not supposed to and I cant figure out the pattern.   could you pls explain to me how this line work ?     rodel.sort(function comp(a,b){return a-b}); what is a and b in this . Thanks again.. I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: It's supposed to sort `rodel` in ascending order, but it takes the values themselves into account (not just the first character of the object). `a` and `b` are consecutive (by index) objects of the range (`rodel`). Can you give me `Logger.log(rodel)`? I don't see the problem.

Comment: Done (I think). I don't see your table, though.

Comment: Thanks Jose..Sorry for the late reply.. I let the users aware of the error and now using the old script.. I will try this new script and let you know.. thanks a ton for your time and efforts.. you are awesome.. cheers!